# Como filtrar, selecionar e contar dados em um pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Como obter quantidade de registros baseados em múltiplas colunas de um determinado nome?

Meu dataframe é mais ou menos assim:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["1111", True, True, False, True, True],
                   ["2222", True, False, True, True, False],
                   ["3333", True, False, True, True, True]],
                  columns=["id", "coluna_qualquer", "x_a", "x_b", "x_c", "x_d"])
```

Eu quero o número de linhas em que tenha pelo menos três colunas com o valor `True`, mas considerando apenas as colunas que iniciam com "*x_*", e não considerar o valor de outras colunas (como a "*coluna_qualquer*"). Nesse exemplo, as linhas com IDs "1111" e "3333" respeitariam essa condição, ou seja, o retorno que eu quero seria 2.

Como fazer isso usando pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## resumindo

Alguns passos separados são necessários para isso. O objeto DataFrame é feito de forma que a chamada a um método retorna um novo dataframe modificado, e você já pode concatenar direto a próxima operação. Então, para filtrar todas as linhas em que as colunas "x_*" tenham mais de 3 `True` e pegar o número total, basta fazer:

```
In [98]: (df.filter(like='x_').sum(axis=1) >= 3).sum()
Out[98]: 2
```

## Vamos por partes

A primeira coisa é selecionar um subdataframe com as colunas desejadas. 
Pandas tem o método `filter` que permite isso - apenas as colunas que contém o texto passado no argumento `like` são selecionadas:

```
In [91]: filtered_df = df.filter(like='x_')

In [92]: filtered_df
Out[92]: 
     x_a    x_b   x_c    x_d
0   True  False  True   True
1  False   True  True  False
2  False   True  True   True
```

(Se o Pandas não tivesse isso, o caminho seria usar Python puro pra selecionar os nomes das colunas desejadas

```
...
data_columns = [col_name for col_name in df.columns if col_name.startswith("x_")]
```

E em seguida método `loc` do dataframe, que aceita os nomes de um  "selecionar tudo", deixando o valor `:`:

```
filtered_df = df.loc[:, data_columns]
```

)

Nesse momento você tem só as colunas que te interessam, e podemos fazer a contagem -

```
     x_a    x_b   x_c    x_d
0   True  False  True   True
1  False   True  True  False
2  False   True  True   True
```

Aqui, podemos abusar de uma característica do Python - os valores `False` e `True` é uma subclasse de números inteiros, e podem participar de uma soma como se fossem 0 e 1 respectivamente. Então, o método `sum` do próprio dataframe pode dar o valor da soma de cada linha da tabela (só precisamos indicar que queremos a soma das linhas passando `axis=1`, caso contrário o `sum` resulta na soma dos valores em cada coluna:

```
In [93]: count_df = filtered_df.sum(axis=1)

In [94]: count_df
Out[94]: 
0    3
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

(Se o valor a ser localizado não fosse True, ou o desejado não fosse só contar as ocorrências, em vez do `.sum`, usariamos o `.apply` - que permite passar uma função genérica que vai receber cada linha do dataframe (ou cada coluna se axis==0), e gerar um resultado.)

E por fim, para saber quantas dessas linhas tem valor acima de 3 - aplicamos o operador `>= 3` o pandas redefine todos os operadores binários - sejam aritméticos ou de comparação, para criarem um novo dataframe, com o resultado da operação em cada célula - ou seja:

```
In [95]: count_df >= 3
Out[95]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

E aí é só repetir o `sum`, desta vez deixando ele somar os `True` na coluna:

```
In [95]: (count_df >= 3).sum()
Out[95]: 2
```